# Is there any r function to split data frame into multiple rows that met criteria

Tags: r, for-loop, split

I have this table with X2 column is amount of item in column X1

```
X1 X2
a   1000000
b   2000000
c   2
d   40
```

I want to transform above table to this table with condition that if amount is larger or equal to 10^6 that r would help me to split the row with amount met condition into multiple rows that have amount less than 10^6 (of course total amount will equal to the source one).

```
X1 X2
a  100000 (X2 = 100000 = 10^5<10^6)
a  100000
a  100000
a  100000
a  100000
a  100000
a  100000
a  100000
a  100000
a  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
b  100000
c 2
d 40
```

(in general, amount 1000000 will split into 10 rows that have the same amount 100000, amount 2000000 will split into 20 rows that have the same amount 100000, amount 2 and 40 keep remain the same). In case of amount is not the number that can be totally divided by 10^n, we will split the amount into the number of rows that can have amount met condition: i have idea to use for loop to repeat the split process until it have the amount of each row met condition)
Anyone can help me to solve this problem?
Many thanks

Comment: I don't understand *"In case of amount is not the number that can be totally divided by 10^n, we will split the amount into the number of rows that can have amount met condition:"*. If your first row was, say, `1000006`, what result would you want?

Comment: Sounds like you should employ the modulus in your calculation. That will give you the "remainder" of whatever is left over after n divisions of 10^5. It was not clear how you decided to use 10^5 as the buckets to split the numbers, but you can program this up if you are using an arbritrary n. Anyway, the main idea is to do integer division (of 10^n 
 using the `div()` function) and use the `replicate` function to repeat the rows with that 10^n value. Add in the "last" row with the `mod()` function as that's the remainder.

Comment: I would recommend checking if the value is less than the target before doing this computation. I imagine there are faster ways to do this, but just trying to think out loud for what might be an easy MVP to accomplish this.